# navigate to nested named view with ui-router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, nested-views

In app I have named view **mainContent**.

```
    <div class = "wrapper"
         ui-view = "mainContent">
    </div>
```

I have only one route for this view.

```
    $stateProvider
        .state("home",
        {
            url: "/home",
            views: {
                'mainContent': {
                    templateUrl: "app/home/home.html"
                }
            }
        });
```

I load home.html to named view mainContent view which has also named view **appContent**.

**home.html**

```
    <div class = "row"
         ui-view = "appContent">
    </div>
```

Routes for nested named view appContent are here.

```
    $stateProvider
        .state("request",
        {
            parent: "home",
            abstract: true,
            url: "/request"
        })
        .state("request.create", {
            url: "/create",
            views: {
                appContent: {
                    templateUrl: "app/requests/create/createRequest.html",
                    controller: "RequestController as vm"
                }
            }
        });
```

When I try load **http://.../#/home/request/create** RequestController is not created and also view createRequest.html is not loaded.

From view navigate to request.create state with :

```
<a ui-sref = "request.create"><i class = "fa fa-plus"></i>New</a>
```

Thank

Comment: You missed the `.` on the `state("home")`, it should be `.state("home")`

Comment: @Shaohao Lin: I fixed it.  It was only copy & paste problem. In code it’s correct.

Comment: How about the problem? Fixed the problem as well?

Comment: @Shaohao Lin: Problem with navigation is not fixed

Comment: Can you explain why `.state(request)` has `parent: "home"`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your "request" state needs its own template an ui-view where you can open its child view

```
$stateProvider
    .state("home",
    {
        url: "/home",
        views: {
            'mainContent': {
                template: "<div class ='row' ui-view ='appContent'></div>"
            }
        }
    })
    .state("request",
    {
        parent: "home",
        abstract: true,
        url: "/request",
        views: {
            'appContent': {
                template: "<div class ='row' ui-view ='requestContent'></div>"
            }
        }
    })
    .state("request.create", {
        url: "/create",
        views: {
            'requestContent': {
                template: "<p>Create Request</p>"
            }
        }
    });
```

This works for me. Proof: http://jsfiddle.net/eD3MU/373/

Comment: thank for sample, I needed add named view also to abstract state